# How to move output of find command to another directory?

Tags: command-line, find, mv

I want the output of this command `find /home -name *.pdf` 
to move the files in the search result to another directory, e.g. with a pipe. How can I do that?

Comment: Just for clarification: you want to move the found files (and not just save the  lines you get from find)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need any pipe-ing, and `xargs` to make the filenames as arguments for `mv`.

Just use `mv` within the `-exec` action of `find`:

```
find /home -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec mv -t /destination {} +
```

- Replace `/destination` with the actual destination directory
- `find` will handle all possible filenames
- `find` will handle `ARG_MAX` by passing as many filenames in one go so that does not trigger `ARG_MAX`
- If you are looking for only files (presumably in this case), limit the search vector by adding `-type f`
- Quote the glob expansion, `'*.pdf'`, so that shell does not expand them beforehand as `find` will handle them

---

If for some weird reason, or for learning purpose, you must use pipe-`xargs`:

```
find /home -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /destination
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have spaces in the names of your pdf's, another way to do it is to run this command in your terminal:

```
mv $(find /home -type f -name '*.pdf') ./destination
```

The `$()` applies the output from the command run (`find /home -type f -name '*.pdf'`) to the command outside of it (`mv [...] ./destination`).

Comment: Of course this breaks if any of the file names have spaces... Which is actually not rare at all with PDF files.

Comment: @hyde, hmm, good point, I hadn't thought of that.  I use this command regularly for moving jpegs, but they don't have special characters in their file names.   Editted.